# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila dinámicamente con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario donde le agrego dinámicamente filas, ahora necesito eliminarle (una a una, en caso de ser necesario) pero me eliminá todo.

Mi formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('store') }}">
@csrf

<div id="myDiv">

    <div class="form-group row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <input id="date" class="form-control @error('date') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" name="date[]" placeholder="{{ __('Date') }}" onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" required>

            @error('date')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
            <input id="hours" type="text" class="form-control @error('hours') is-invalid @enderror" name="hours[]" value="{{ old('hours') }}" placeholder="{{ __('Hours') }}" required autocomplete="hours">

            @error('hours')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <textarea id="comments" type="text" class="form-control" name="comments[]" value="{{ old('comments') }}" required placeholder="{{ __('Comments') }}" autocomplete="comments"></textarea>

            @error('comments')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<button id="agregar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-4">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ __('Add a row') }}
</button>

<button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger my-4">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ __('Delete a row') }}
</button>

<div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
            {{ __('Register') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi script

```
<script>
$("#agregar").on('click',
    function () {
        $("#myDiv").append('<hr><div class="form-group row mb-2"><div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0"><input id="date" class="form-control" type="text" name="date[]" placeholder="{{ __('Date') }}" onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type=date)" onblur="(this.type=text)" required></div><div class="col-md-6 mb-2"><input id="hours" type="text" class="form-control" name="hours[]" placeholder="{{ __('Hours') }}" required autocomplete="hours"></div></div><div class="form-group row mb-3"><div class="col-md-12 mb-2 mb-md-0"><textarea id="comments" type="text" class="form-control" name="comments[]" value="{{ old('comments') }}" required placeholder="{{ __('Comments') }}" autocomplete="comments"></textarea></div></div>');
    }
);

$("#eliminar").on('click',function(){
    $("#myDiv").remove();
});
```

Comment: Yo pondria el botón `Eliminar` por fila, cuando haces el `append`, a la vez que tambien identificaria el `<div class="form-group row mb-2">` con un `id=` único, que luego, en el botón `Eliminar` de cada fila lo llamara de forma inequívoca para su eliminacion, mediante un `onclick="borrame(id)"` o bien dentro del javascript poniendolo a la escucha.

Comment: Gracias, trataré de hacerlo así.